# Deshabilitar options en select si hay mas de un valor igual

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-select

Estoy creando el contenido de un < select > desde un archivo de PHP haciendo una consulta a una BD donde me trae las revisiones que cada usuario debe de hacer cada día (si tiene una revisión el día de hoy simplemente dice "Hoy", si son anteriores le pone la fecha de cuando es). Se supone que si hay una misma revisión 2 o mas veces todas excepto la mas vieja se deben de deshabilitar y solo puede hacer la mas vieja y si la completa se debe de deshabilitar la siguiente mas vieja y así consecutivamente hasta que solo quede la de "Hoy" para poder realizarla. El problema es que al dar el salto de fecha no deshabilita algunas opciones que están repetidas.

Este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
public function asignaciones_hoy($id){
    try{
        $fechai=strtotime("today"); $fechaf=strtotime("tomorrow"); $txt='';
        $consulta=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT hr.id as idrevision,hr.id_procedimiento as idprocedimiento,hr.fecha_inicio as fechai,hr.termino,hp.procedimiento as nombre FROM HUB_Revisiones as hr JOIN HUB_Procedimientos as hp ON hr.id_procedimiento=hp.id WHERE hr.id_usuario=:id AND hr.termino=0 AND hr.fecha_inicio<:fechai order by hr.fecha_inicio asc");
        $consulta->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT); $consulta->bindValue(':fechai',$fechai,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $consulta->execute();
        $primer_resagado=1;
        $nueva_revision='';
        $resagados=$consulta->fetchAll();
        foreach($resagados as $resagado){
            if ($primer_resagado==1) {
                $txt.='<option value="' .$resagado['idrevision']. '">' .$resagado['nombre']. ' <span style="color: #eb4034">('.strftime("%a %d de %b %Y",$resagado['fechai']).')</span></option>';
                $primer_resagado=$primer_resagado+1;
                $nueva_revision=$resagado['idprocedimiento'];
            }else{
                if ($resagado['idprocedimiento']==$nueva_revision && $primer_resagado>1) {
                    $txt.='<option value="' .$resagado['idrevision']. '" disabled>' .$resagado['nombre']. ' <span style="color: #eb4034">('.strftime("%a %d de %b %Y",$resagado['fechai']).')</span></option>';
                    $nueva_revision=$resagado['idprocedimiento'];
                } else {
                    $txt.='<option value="' .$resagado['idrevision']. '">' .$resagado['nombre']. ' <span style="color: #eb4034">('.strftime("%a %d de %b %Y",$resagado['fechai']).')</span></option>';
                    $nueva_revision=$resagado['idprocedimiento'];
                }
            }
        }
        $consulta=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT hr.id as idrevision,hp.procedimiento,hr.id_procedimiento as idprocedimiento,hr.fecha_inicio as fechai,hr.termino FROM HUB_Revisiones as hr JOIN HUB_Procedimientos as hp JOIN Usuarios as u ON hr.id_procedimiento=hp.id AND hr.id_usuario=u.id WHERE hr.id_usuario=:id AND hr.termino=0 AND hr.fecha_inicio>:fechai AND hr.fecha_inicio<:fechaf");
        $consulta->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT); $consulta->bindValue(':fechai',$fechai,PDO::PARAM_INT); $consulta->bindValue(':fechaf',$fechaf,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $consulta->execute();
        $procedimientos=$consulta->fetchAll();
        foreach($procedimientos as $procedimiento){
            $pendiente=$this->bd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM HUB_Revisiones as hr JOIN HUB_Procedimientos as hp ON hr.id_procedimiento=hp.id WHERE hr.id_usuario=:id  AND hr.termino=0 AND hr.fecha_inicio<:fechai AND hr.id_procedimiento=:idprocedimiento  GROUP BY hr.id_procedimiento");
            $pendiente->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT); $pendiente->bindValue(':fechai',$fechai,PDO::PARAM_INT); $pendiente->bindValue(':idprocedimiento',$procedimiento['idprocedimiento'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $pendiente->execute();
            $datos=$pendiente->fetchColumn();
            if($datos!=0) $txt.='<option value="' .$procedimiento['idrevision']. '" disabled>' .$procedimiento['procedimiento']. ' (Hoy)</option>';
            else $txt.='<option value="' .$procedimiento['idrevision']. '">' .$procedimiento['procedimiento']. ' (Hoy)</option>';
        }
        return $txt;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y el resultado en < select > se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí, por ejemplo, la revisión de "Creación de muebles en proyecto" ya esta para hacer el 25/oct/2019 y se supone que esa es la ultima pero después hay una del 02/oct/2020 y se puede seleccionar cuando no debería.

De antemano gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Me pregunto por qué hay duplicidad de datos cuando lo puedes evitar fácilmente en la consulta... A veces el problema está en otra parte (en este caso quizá en la lógica que estás implementando).

Comment: De hecho lo que viene siendo las consultas fueron hechas por otro compañero de trabajo hace años, solo que nunca supo el porque no funciono lo de deshabilitar los options. Ya intente cambiarla a una sola consulta pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Yo alguna vez tuve que realizar algo similar para evaluaciones de asesores, y me funciono mas usar un custom select, generado desde html y css, en el que pude personalizar mas cada opción, como quitar el cursor, identificar cada uno con color faltantes, pasados y realizados, además quitar evento individual según mis reglas, no tengo actualmente el código, pero busca un custom select y te será mas funcional y amigable.

Comment: Tal vez podría funcionar, pero aquí el detalle es que lo que se pide es que el usuario no pueda realizar la misma revisión pero de otras fechas mientras tenga varias. Primero debe de terminar las revisiones atrasadas y después ya puede realizar las revisiones del día actual.